# Answer pretends to be accepted but actually not.

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer

The following answer is currently not accepted, but after enabling full site it is shown to be accepted. (on Android, Google chrome)

Consider:

**Mobile view- Activity page:**

> [image: MA]

**Mobile view- Profile page:**

> [image: MP]

**Full site enabled- Activity page:**

> [image: FA]

**Full site enabled- Profile page:**

> [image: FP]

Looks like a bug.

Note: The question with the mentioned answer currently has another accepted answer.

Comment: This is a bug related to the recently rolled-out activity page changes. It's already recorded in the global meta thread about issues related to the new activity page [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372716#372716), and is currently listed as status-planned, which means SE is looking in to fixing it.

Comment: Additionally evidence: [in this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34413/my-activity-summary-shows-an-answer-is-accepted-when-it-isnt).