# My activity summary shows an answer is accepted, when it isn't.

Tags: bug, user-interface, accepted-answer

My [latest answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341423/mathbbr2-is-not-a-subspace-of-mathbbc2/4341433#4341433) is showing up as accepted in my activity summary, when it isn't (and never was). Just thought I'd let you know.

In case anything changes, here is my unaccepted answer (and actually accepted answer):
[image]

and here is my activity:

[image]

Comment: It seems to have happened [here as well](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34370/answer-pretends-to-be-accepted-but-actually-not), earlier this month. I haven't read that post recently, but your post reminded me of it.  Sorry I'm not clear why. :(

Comment: After reading that question and responses, it seems to be undergoing a "status-review"; take a look-see at that earlier meta question.  This could add helpful data.

Comment: I'm glad it's already flagged, but it's not really a big deal. It's also worth noting that the gold badge I'm tracking has drifted somewhat. I probably should make an account on meta for this stuff.